# Mongo filter by dates that overlap both start and end dates

Tags: mongodb, date, datetime, calendar

#### Question

Given a `startQuery` and `endQuery`, what Mongo filter will find documents with dates that overlap both query values?

By 'overlap,' I mean that the matching documents have a:

1. `start` before the `startQuery` AND
2. `end` after the `endQuery` AND
3. Have dates in between the `startQuery` and `endQuery`

---

#### Expected Behavior

`startQuery` and `endQuery`: `2022-01-10`, `2022-01-20`

Documents:

```js
[
// 01-01 is before 01-10 and 02-02 is after 01-10
{title: "match1", start: "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z", end: "2022-02-02T00:00:00Z"},

// 01-15 and 01-16 are between 01-10 and 01-15
{title: "notMatch1", start: "2022-01-15T00:00:00Z", end: "2022-01-16T00:00:00Z"},

// 01-16 is not after 01-20
{title: "notMatch2", start: "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z", end: "2022-01-16T00:00:00Z"},
]
```

Return:

```
[{title: "match1", start: "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z", end: "2022-12-31T00:00:00Z"}]
```

---

#### Context

This is for finding events to display in a week view of a calendar. Filtering by `startOfWeek` to `endOfWeek` misses events that span 3 weeks and overlap the second week.

##### My best guess

Is this the best way? If so, how can I translate it to a Mongo filter?

```js
queryStart = dayjs(start).dayOfYear() //10
queryEnd = dayjs(end).dayOfYear() //20 
queryArray = [10,11,12...18,19,20]    

for each document
   // this document's start and end:
   // 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z, 2022-02-02T00:00:00Z
   eventStart = dayjs(start).dayOfYear() // 1 (01-01)
   eventEnd = dayjs(end).dayOfYear()    //  33 (02-02)
   eventArray = [1,2,3, .... 31,32,33] 

   // true
   isMatch = (
               eventStart not between queryStart and queryEnd 
                &&
               eventEnd not between queryStart and queryEnd 
                &&
               any(eventArray) in (queryArray)
             )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      start: {
        "$lte": "2022-01-10"
      },
      end: {
        "$gte": "2022-01-20"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ip68sex21Xz)

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$and": [
          {
            "$lte": [
              { $week: { "$toDate": "$start" } },
              { $week: { "$toDate": "2022-01-10" } }
            ]
          },
          {
            "$gte": [
              { $week: { "$toDate": "$end" } },
              { $week: { "$toDate": "2022-01-20" } }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tt1MpMiClVX)

Comment: The first option worked best for me. Gotta love when the solution is way simpler that expected. 

I believe using the week number like in the second option could introduce some bugs if dates are longer than a year (because an event on `Jan 1 2022` and `Jan 1 2023` would have the same week number of `1`)